# Flask repeating function by keep pressing a button

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

today I've been trying to resolve this problem, but I can't figure it out how to "fix".

I'm creating a website using Flask, and when I'm clicking a button placed in a post form, I'd like to keep an action doing; to be more accurate, when I click the button, an action should be performed, but I'd like this action to be performed more times if I keep pressing the button. This is the structure of my layout and code.

Here is the python code

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, render_template, request
)

from webapp.Utilities.utilities import SerialHandler
from webapp.blueprints.decorators import login_required

bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

serial_scheduler = SerialHandler()


@bp.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        button = request.form['press_to_run']
        foo()
    return render_template('index.html', title="Index")
```

And here the HTML structure

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block stylesheet %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

  <div class="container new_container">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-header">
        Featured
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="{{ url_for('video.video') }}" alt="">
  </div>

  <form class="" method="post">
    <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
      <button style="width:33.3%">Apple</button>
      <button style="width:33.3%">Samsung</button>
      <button style="width:33.3%">Sony</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="container new_container">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <button onclick="switch_theme()" class="btn btn-light shadow-none" id="switch_button" style="width: 15%;">Dark Mode</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function switch_theme() {
      const theme = document.getElementById('switch_theme').className;

      if(theme === "dark-theme") {
        document.getElementById('switch_theme').className = "light-theme";
        document.getElementById('switch_button').className = "btn btn-dark shadow-none";
        document.getElementById('switch_button').innerHTML = "Light Mode";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('switch_theme').className = "dark-theme";
        document.getElementById('switch_button').className = "btn btn-light shadow-none";
        document.getElementById('switch_button').innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
      }
    }
  </script>

{% endblock %}
```

To conclude I say that I don't necessarily need a solution with python, but I would also be fine with a solution that include maybe a javascript function that runs the python function of my SerialHandler object.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided doesn't help much. From what I understood you want to call your flask API endpoint (that will call the python function) repeatedly if someone keeps pressing a button inside a form element. This can be done in the front end with JavaScript itself. Something like -

```html
<form method="POST">
  <button id="formbutton">Click me!</button>
</form>

<script>
  // grab the button
  formBtn = document.querySelector('#formbutton')
  let isMouseDown = false

  // don't send the form automatically
  formBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  })

  // keep track of isMouseDown
  formBtn.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isMouseDown = true
  })

  formBtn.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    isMouseDown = false
  })

  // how many times to call the backend
  setInterval(function() {
    if(isMouseDown) {
      // can also use axios & pass custom data
      fetch('http://your.server/end/point', {
        method: 'POST'
      }).then(res => console.log(resres))
    }
  }, 200)

</script>
```

This may not be the best way to do it but will get the job done. If there are multiple buttons just add them in an array & add event listeners on them in a loop.